# How can i use entrypoint in dockerfile for Volume command to display the result when my container is stop

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile, jmeter-4.0

My Docker File link:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/uiu3q6qdpmqst2f/Screenshot%202018-04-26%2010.01.59.png?dl=0

I am using this commands

docker build -t jmeter123 .

docker run -v /var/www/html/"$(date +%Y%m%d)":/opt/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/result_html  jmeter123:latest

how can i update the html report with timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your HTML report name to current timestamp amend your `CMD` section to include `-Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=$(date +%Y%m%d)` stanza, for example:

```
CMD ./bin/jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=$(date +%Y%m%d) -n -t ./bin/Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx -l ./bin/result.jtl -e -o ./bin/result_html
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Reporting configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)